# List all existing calendar resources with Google service account (Directory API)

Tags: node.js, api, google-api, google-directory-api

I can't get all company calendar resources via service account and Directory API. All good when I fetch the resources with my user account. Somehow service account and my user account do not share company calendar resources. The response I get with the service account:

```
config: {
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/resources/calendars',
method: 'GET',
paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
headers: {
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
  'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)',
  Authorization: 'Bearer <access_token>',
  Accept: 'application/json'
},
params: [Object: null prototype] {},
validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
responseType: 'json'
 },
  code: 404,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Resource Not Found',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'notFound'
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I make my service account get the resources?

Comment: In order to get all calendars with the service account you need to do either or of the following: 1. Shared all company calendars with the service account or 2. Impersonate your user with the service account. I'll go with the later one, much easier.

Comment: @Morfinismo, I tried to make impersonation but I get 401. As I understood I must enable domain-wide delegation to make it work, I even added the permission where the service account is the owner of the user account. Unfortunately, no luck( 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up delegation to a user on your workspace domain to delegate as.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@yourdomain.com')
```